# Proof of Triangle Inequality Wikipedia Proof Explanation

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation

According to wikipedia, to prove the triangle inequality

$|x + y| \leq |x|+|y|$

Proof:

$-\left\vert x \right\vert \leq x \leq \left\vert x \right\vert $

and

$-\left\vert y \right\vert \leq y \leq \left\vert y \right\vert$ .... We interrupt the proof to ask a question.

I don't know how the proof was derived. 
I assume we let y=0, x=0 separately. Then what did we do to derive $-\left\vert x \right\vert \leq x \leq \left\vert x \right\vert $ and $-\left\vert y \right\vert \leq y \leq \left\vert y \right\vert$ ?

Let's say x is 5. Then x is bounded between -5 and 5. How does this work?

Comment: Break it into cases. What is $|x|$ if $x\ge 0$? What is $|x|$ if $x<0$?

Comment: How is $5$ not bounded between $-5$ and $5$?

Comment: @ZacharySelk Yes this is what I am talking about. I am wondering if the OP is confused about $-5\leq 5\leq 5$.

Comment: @Dave Yeah I didn't see your "not"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x \ge 0$, then by definition $|x| = x\ge 0$,

$$-1\le 1 \le 1 \implies -|x| \le x \le |x|$$

If $x < 0$, then by definition $|x| = -x > 0$,

$$-1\le -1 \le 1 \implies -|x|\le x \le |x|$$

Answer (score 1):

I thing the following reasoning is a bit of better.

We need to prove that
$$\left(|x+y|\right)^2\leq\left(|x|+|y|\right)^2$$ or
$$xy\leq|xy|,$$
which is obvious.